# Calculate a Light value of a specific tile in an infinite world, given the lighing positions

Tags: java, math, game-development, lighting

I am making a Tile based infinite world game (Similar to Notch's Minicraft) and i am trying to implement light. Here is the function i use:

**The arguments it takes are the World itself, and the tiles position relative to world co-ordinates**

```java
public static Vector.Vector3f calculateLight(World w, int worldx, int worldy){
        float tileLightValue = 0;
        float totalLights = 0;

        for(Light currentLight : BlockLighting.lights){ // for each light
            float currentLightXWorldPosition = currentLight.x;
            float currentLightYWorldPosition = currentLight.y;
            float distanceBetweenPoints = Core.MathFunctions.getDistance(
                    worldx,worldy,
                    currentLightXWorldPosition, currentLightYWorldPosition
            );

            if(distanceBetweenPoints < currentLight.range){
                tileLightValue += distanceBetweenPoints / 20.175f;
                totalLights += 1;
            }
        }
        
        float lig = Core.MathFunctions.fclamp(((tileLightValue * -2.4f) + (69.3f / 100)), 0 , 1);

        if(totalLights > 0){
            return new Vector.Vector3f(lig,lig,lig);
        }else{
            // If no lights, return 0 as to not change the ambient light.
            return new Vector.Vector3f(0,0,0);
        }
    }
```

Calculations are then made by taking the light value of this function, and then adding it to the base lighting (ambient)

```java
...
Core.MathFunctions.fclamp(daylight + light, 0, 1)
...
```

And produces the **Intended** result:[image]

But When the lights intersect, i get this **glitch** :[image]

So it has to be a mathematical issue. So im hoping someone could offer a solution to this issue or modify my code to send me in the correct direction, the best way to describe the function is:

Given a list of light points, and a position of a tile. Calculate the appropriate lighting for said tile in an infinite world, so that when it is added to the ambient lighting of the world it produces a Terraria like lighting effect.

**Note the code showing the ambient light calculation (2nd code block) is more or less pseudo-code, the actual code uses the Vector3 for color calculation, and that works fine, just thought id strip it down to lessen confusion**

Edit: Here is a JSFiddle using the exact same code, to illustrate the issue. So you can see it, and tinker with it!

[Interactive JS Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dravenlewis/o93kaLbj/1/)

Comment: Can you explain what this code is doing? `((tileLightValue * -2.4f) + (69.3f / 100))`

Comment: Sure! Its basically a tuning function, gets the lights exactly how i like them. we take the ```tileLightValue``` (Which was calculated by taking the sum of the distance of the points divided by 20.175 in order to smooth out the gradient) this creates the inverse of what we want so me have to multiply by a negative and ~-2,4 keeps the gradient im looking for (more artistic than anything) the value 0.693 is also for tuning the lighting intensity.

tl;dl its just specific tuning to get the light to look how i want, the glitch i mentioned above still happens without this tuning.

Comment: OK I think I understand.  Light is inversely proportional to distance ( 1/distance, not distance*negative slope) but that's fine if you want that look.  The first thing I can think of is that your `fclamp()` function isn't working, so please post the code for that.

Comment: `public static float fclamp(float i, float min, float max) {
            return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, i));
 }`

Comment: @markspace hey! just an update, i added a Javascript implementation in the form of a fiddle if you would like to check the code and maybe give me some pointers, as well as tinker and play with it!